# Typescript "Object is possibly 'undefined'" for object literal

Tags: typescript

In the browser console I can do this in js just fine:

```
[{ssid: 'Test Network 1', rssi: 54},{ssid: 'Test Network 2', rssi: 60}].find((rec) => 'Test Network 1' === rec.ssid).rssi

54
```

When I attempt the exact same thing in my Typescript app, Typescript says "Object is possibly 'undefined'":

```
[{ssid: 'Test Network 1', rssi: 54},{ssid: 'Test Network 2', rssi: 60}].find((rec) => 'Test Network 1' === rec.ssid).rssi;
```

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Because `Array.prototype.find()` can return `undefined`, you can use optional chaining to make your code type safe... `find(...)?.rssi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find method may not find what your looking for and be possibly undefined. You can use '?'.

```
[{ssid: 'Test Network 1', rssi: 54},{ssid: 'Test Network 2', rssi: 60}].find((rec) => 'Test Network 1' === rec.ssid)?.rssi;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the question mark after the closing round bracket, `find` can return undefined if there is no object that matches the condition, and although in your example this will never happen it is still something you need to check by doing optional chaining.

`[{ssid: 'Test Network 1', rssi: 54},{ssid: 'Test Network 2', rssi: 60}].find((rec) => 'Test Network 1' === rec.ssid)?.rssi;`